# stackoverflow dark theme and show user logo

Tags: image, themes

**How can show user photo in dark theme**

```
<img src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/2680724.png?theme=dark" ...
```

Comment: this code is about flair stackoverflow .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
< .. img src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/2285592.png?theme=dark" ..>
```

should suffice as described in your flairs page. I don't see all your html code there, but this works just fine for me.

Brgds,
Stian